# How to dismiss multiple (all) modals at once?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is there a way to dismiss multiple modals or only one by one like this: `Navigation.ModalPopAsync()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Modals you have to do one by one because its on the `Modal Stack`
For Navigation Stack you can use `Navigation.PopToRootAsync()`

Also you can try not `await`the `Navigation.ModalPopAsync()` and also pass animation as false.

You can find more details in this forum post- [PopToRootAsync with Modal](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22156/poptorootasync-with-modal)

Comment: here they state that not awaiting may cause a deadlock https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PopModalAsync()/

Comment: It says : Calling `Task.Wait` may cause a deadlock if a previous call to INavigation.PushModal or INavigation.PopModal has not completed. But yes its best to `await`

Answer (score 21):

I've actually written something to pop all modals.

It works by first figuring out how many modals are active then by popping them.

And yes, as Rohit Vipin Mathews mentioned in his answer, `PopModalAsync(false);` will remove the animation.

```
// Get number of modals on the Navigation Stack
int numModals = Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count;

// Pop each modal in the stack
for (int currModal = 0; currModal < numModals; currModal++)
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Comment: you can also pass false to .PopModalAsync() to do it without animation